# React Checkbox onChange not triggering toggleTodo function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management

I'm building a simple React todo list application, and I'm having trouble with the onChange event not triggering my toggleTodo function when clicking the checkboxes. I expected that clicking a checkbox would toggle the completed state of a todo item, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended.

I've added an additional console.log statement to check if the function is running or not. I found out it was not working.

Here's my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    setNewItem(target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTodos((curr) => {
      return [
        ...curr,
        {
          id: crypto.randomUUID(),
          title: newItem,
          completed: false,
        },
      ];
    });
    // to clear the input box
    setNewItem("");
  };

  const toggleTodo = (id, completed) => {
    console.log("toggleTodo has been invoked");
    setTodos((curr) => {
      return curr.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return { ...todo, completed};
        }
        return todo;
      });
    });
  };
    
  return (
    <>
      <form className="new-item-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-row">
          <label htmlFor="item">New todo</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name=""
            id="item"
            value={newItem}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit" className="btn">
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h1 className="header">Todo List</h1>
      <ul className="list">`your text`
        {todos.map((todo) => {
          return (
            <li key={todo.id}>
              <label htmlFor="item1">{todo.title}</label>
              <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                checked={todo.completed}
                onChange = {(e) => toggleTodo(todo.id, e.target.checked)}
              />
              <button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: can you remove the spacing between the ```=```

Comment: Hi @matt! Well it does update the state on every checkbox clicking. Sorry, I tried your code, and read the question 4 times but I can't quite get what the problem is. You want to update the list of `todos` or `checkedTodos`?